# "File does not exist" error on mod_rewrite (WordPress permalink)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I'm trying to configure WordPress permalinks on Linode server running Ubuntu. The permalinks are not working even after doing the basic tricks for configuring them.

.htaccess -file has been given permission "777" and WP has rewritten it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mydirectory/mysubdirectory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mydirectory/mysubdirectory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have configured "etc/apache2/sites-available/default in a following way:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
   <Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride ALL
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
   </Directory>
   <Directory /var/www/mydomin.com/public_html/mydirectory/>
      RewriteEngine On
      AllowOverride ALL
   </Directory>
```

As you can see I've tried to set "AllowOverride" to different folders. I just gave it a shot, thought that maybe something is overriding the rule for certain folders.

I have ran "a2enmod rewrite" command on Terminal and mod_rewrite is enabled.

I have restarted my Apache every time I've made changes.

When I navigating on my WordPress site I get "Page not found" error. Apache error log says following:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/mydirectory/mysubdirectory/
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the path to your site physically on the server? Your document root is /var/www but you are trying to enable rewrite on /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/mydirectory/mysubdirectory/

Comment: @Omnikrys it is /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/mydirectory/mysubdirectory. That's where I've installed the WordPress. The site is installed to subfolder because it's a dev environment. But now I'm a bit confused. How my document root can be /var/www when all my actual websites files are supposed to be located at /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/ folder?

Comment: Are you using virtual hosts?

Comment: @Omnikrys yes. I'm running my server on Linode and I configured the virtual hosts according to their documentation.

Comment: We need to see your virtual hosts settings too. Also, it is good practice to put everything together. Did the WP site work prior to attempting to enable permalinks?

Comment: @Omnikrys Okay, I wasn't aware that the virtual host settings are related also. I'm not sure if I'm following, what do you mean by putting everything together? WordPress worked properly as far as I know and it wrote the .htaccess file after I changed the file permissions of the file.

Comment: @Omnikrys yes it was the virtual hosts. Eventually I found out that there is also mydomain.com.conf file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/ folder. I set /var/www/ AllowOverride All there, and now it works like a charm. If you wanna write an answer below, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below settings can go in your VirtualHost directive for the site in question. In most cases this is located in a separate file and referenced from the main conf file for the server.

```
RewriteEngine On
AllowOverride ALL
```

Generally speaking you want to keep all of the settings for each site in their own file. So if you need to tweak anything else do it in the file containing the VirtualHost directive for that site. It makes it much easier to troubleshoot/maintain in the future.